# zf2 mvc event-listener or strategy

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, partial-views, event-listener

im new to Zf2, i recently upgraded from zf1 and need help and advice on this problem. 
Here the fact :
I'm working on medical project (which is an upgrade to a zf1 version) in some controller (page) i need to have the **patient**'s info and current **visitation** in sidebar panel...
I know i'm new to zf2 but i don't want to do redundant things like having in every action the **getvisiteService()** and **patientService()** retrieve info and passing these results to view over and over.
I thought about a plugin but again i have to pass from controller to view and supercharge my view with partials and placeholder helper (grr!!!)
Thinkin' about **Strategy** and **eventlistener** but i don't know how these work and i need to inject result to a partial.
So there is a simple and/or complicated way to achieve that? Thank you in advance any hint and code will be appreciated and sorry for my poor english i speak french (such a typical excuse :) )

Comment: More than using that approach: did you consider implementing a view helper that has access to the correct service?

Comment: @Ocramius thanks for commenting...No i didn't consider i almost forget that point. It's good point, i'll consider that approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a ton of approaches you could use here, but sticking to your original question, it's quite easy to inject things into your layout model, with something like this:

Module.php

```
/**
 * On bootstrap event
 * 
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // Inject something, like a nav into your Layout view model
    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel(); // Layout View Model
    $navigation= new ViewModel(array(
        'username'  => 'Bob' // Dynamically set some variables..
    ));
    $navigation->setTemplate('navigation/mynav');
    $viewModel->addChild($navigation, 'navigation');
}
```

You could also create a custom view Helper to do the work for you if you wanted

```
<?php
/**
 * MyHelper.php
 */
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class MyHelper extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Invoke
     * 
     * @return  string
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        // Dynamically build your nav or what ever.

        $patientService = $this->getServiceManager()->get('PatientService');

        return 'soemthing';
    }

    /**
     * @var ServiceManager
     */
    protected $serviceManager;

    /**
     * Retrieve service manager instance
     *
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public function getServiceManager() 
    {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * Set service manager instance
     *
     * @param ServiceManager $locator
     * @return User
     */
    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager) 
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Andrew 4 your comments. I opted for the view helper like @Ocramius & you suggest...Here 2 keypoint method
`code`
    public function render($options, $session)
    {
        if (!isset($options['placeholder']))
            $placeholder = $this->placeholder;
        else
            $placeholder = $options['placeholder'];

$placeholderHelper = $this->getView()->plugin('placeholder');
        $placeholderHelper($placeholder)->captureStart();
        echo $this->getView()->render($this->partialFile, array('session' => $session));
        $placeholderHelper($placeholder)->captureEnd();}

Comment: `code`public function __invoke($options = array())
    {
        $session = array();
        if (!$this->hasPatient()) {
            return;
        }

        $patient = $this->getPatientService()->findPatient($this->hasPatient());
        $session['patient'] = $patient;

        if ($this->hasVisite()) {
            $visite = $this->getVisiteService()->find($this->hasPatient());
            $session['visite'] = $visite;
        }

        return $this->render($options, $session);
    }`code`

Comment: Can you help me on this block of code it's like ahem...
`code`$placeholderHelper = $this->getView()->plugin('placeholder');
        $placeholderHelper($placeholder)->captureStart();
        echo $this->getView()->render($this->partialFile, array('session' => $session));
        $placeholderHelper($placeholder)->captureEnd();
return;
`code`
Everything works well but echoing' in method embarrass me